# What exactly does docker swarms dispatcher-heartbeat do?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I am managing a couple of stacks on a couple of nodes running in docker swarm. Unfortunately it seems a worker node lost connection to the single manager I currently have which set the node to a faulty state and closed the running services on that node.

After some searching I see that there is the option to set dispatcher-heartbeat in the swarm with this command.

```
docker swarm --dispatcher-heartbeat 5s
```

Apparently the default is 5 seconds and suggestions say that it is good to set to 30s instead. What exactly does this setting do? Is it possible to set this to a very high number instead? I just want the services to keep running on the node no matter what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we had a similar issue but in combination with VMWare's VSphere (and additional services, which move VMs around the different hosts). At the time when the node was moved it was "down/seemed unreachable" for a few moments but in the swarm, it was already marked as down and services got rescheduled even tho the node came back up instantly.

**So to the question. Docker Swarm uses this parameter (dispatcher-heartbeat) to tell its nodes how often they have to report back their health status. So for instance default value is 5s, so if the node does not respond in a 5s interval it is marked as down/unreachable.**

I have found back then (and I will link the discussion here as well) a notable topic where a company tested the property with 30 60 and 90s on the dispatcher-heartbeat probably worth taking a look.

https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/38321#issuecomment-450138988

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In my case we had some issues due to putting a swarm between some nodes in one network and some nodes in another where the connection between these network sometime could get unstable. The solution I went with temporarily was to increase the dispatcher heartbeat to a high number and the permanent solution (which took a bit longer to execute) was to split the swarm into one swarm per network instead.